# A place that is away from your normal life?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

How do you describe, using a noun, a place you can escape from your old life but only temporarily. It kinda feels like a summer house, but bears no relevance to the seasons. I have thought about the word 'seclusion' but it seems to have nothing to do with a place, rather more like a state.

Comment: Do you actually mean a physical place similar to a [garden shed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man_cave)? Single-word-requests generally need quite [a lot more detail](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info).

Comment: Maybe a Haven ?

ha·ven
noun
a place of safety or refuge.
"a haven for wildlife"
synonyms: refuge, retreat, shelter, sanctuary, asylum, place of safety, place of security, port in a storm, harbor, oasis, sanctum
"a safe haven in times of trouble"

Comment: In the non-physical context, some go to their "happy place." https://www.wikihow.com/Be-in-Your-Happy-Place Whether that fills your need is another question.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest **hideaway** about which the [Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/hideaway) has

> **hideaway**
>
> NOUN
>
> A place used for hiding in or as a retreat from other people.
>
> *‘Little Cayman has to be one of the most peaceful hideaways in the Caribbean.’*
>
> *‘Very young children often have secret hideaways where they go to seek solitude.’*
>
> *‘I love the way the topography lends itself to creating secret hideaways where guests can sit down and enjoy the views in seclusion.’*

Answer (score 1):

In the States, a **getaway** [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/getaway)

> - a place where one escapes for relaxation
> - a period of time for such recreation.

*I need to get to my getaway for awhile to relax and be away from the rat race.*

Answer (score 0):

Such places are commonly called **retreats** as mentioned in the comment. This noun is in a neutral register, whereas **hideaway** and **getaway** are informal.

> Camp David is the country retreat for the President of the United States.

Neither of those informal words could be substituted here without a register-clash:

> Brokered by U.S. President Jimmy Carter between Israeli Prime Minister Menachem Begin and Egyptian President Anwar el-Sādāt and officially titled the “Framework for Peace in the Middle East,” the agreements became known as the Camp David Accords because the negotiations took place at the U.S. presidential <strike>hideaway, getaway</strike> **retreat** at Camp David, Maryland.